# In there a way to derive the inverse value of CDF format MultinormalDistribution?

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, distributions, inverse

Is there a way to produce the inverse value of multinormal distribution function in CDF format with 0.05 significance level?

I found the function called `MultinormalDistribution` but I could not find the way to 
calculate the inverse value of this.

Is there a function or a method that can derive the inverse value of this `MultinormalDistribution`?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Inverse values of `PDF`,`CDF` or what ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks: I've amended the question. You'll see `what` it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dist = MultinormalDistribution[
   {0, 0}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}];

PDF[dist, {x, y}]
```

> E^((1/2)*(-x^2 - y^2))/(2*Pi)

```
CDF[dist, {x, y}]
```

> (1/4)*Erfc[-(x/Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viglP.png))]*Erfc[-(y/Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viglP.png))]

The inverse CDF is not unique. To simplify the problem I will find the inverse CDF with y == x

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[
  CDF[dist, {x, y}],
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  Contours ->
   {.1, .25, .5, .75, .9, .95, .99}],
 Plot[Tooltip[x, "y = x"],
  {x, -3, 3},
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

```
inverseCDF[q_?NumericQ] := 
  t /. NSolve[CDF[dist, {t, t}] == q, t][[1]] //
   Quiet;

inv = inverseCDF[.95]
```

> 1.95451

```
Plot[inverseCDF[q], {q, .001, .999},
 PlotRange -> All,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}],
   Line[{{0, inv}, {.95, inv}, {.95, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

EDIT: For higher dimensional distributions

```
dim = 4;

dist = MultinormalDistribution[ConstantArray[0, dim], 
   IdentityMatrix[dim]];
```

For all of the variables equal,

```
inverseCDF[q_?NumericQ] := 
  t /. NSolve[CDF[dist, ConstantArray[t, dim]] == q, t][[1]] // Quiet;

inv = inverseCDF[.95]
```

> 2.234

```
Plot[inverseCDF[q], {q, .001, .999}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}], 
   Line[{{0, inv}, {.95, inv}, {.95, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for! By the way, may I ask what "[q_?NumericQ]" mean here? I am not sure especially how the question mark comes in. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: `?NumericQ` is a `PatternTest` (highlight `?` and hit `F1` for help) that limits evaluation of the function inverseCDF to numeric arguments. This is necessary since the function uses a numeric technique (i.e., `NSolve`). `NSolve` cannot work with a symbolic q.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would like to ask one more question if you don't mind. If I am trying to set the numbers of "t"s to be equal to the covariance dimension (especially with the column dimensions) that I set up, then how can I reflect this into my code? For example, in "NSolve[CDF[dist, {t, t}] == q, t]", if my covariance is dimension 4, then I should have "NSolve[CDF[dist, {t, t,t,t}] == q, t]". Is there a way to make this synchronized with the covariance matrix that I produce? Thank you very much again for your tremendous helps.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I really do appreciate your help. Then, does this "dim" automatically give the dimension of the covariance matrix..? Or should I define this "dim" separately..?

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Thank you very much again! Sorry about not being very clear about my message initially but actually,I was wondering whether there is a method that can catch the column length of the covariance matrix that can be used as a number of "t"s in the equation. By the way, thank you very much again. This is a quite cool explanation.

Comment: Length[covar] should work

Comment: Thank you very much again. Yes, I guess you are right since covariance length is the same as its column number. Thank you and it was a quite valuable work for all.